# Foreach и sql

Tags: php, sql

```
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $msg);
foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
$where .= "`word` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR"; 
}
```

Здравствуйте. Как сделать, чтобы `OR` был только когда он нужен? Точнее, если слово одно, то `OR` не надо, если более 1 то OR надо но чтобы последний не был с OR в конце, т.е пример:

```
`word` LIKE '%Lala%' or `word` LIKE '%BLA%' or `word` LIKE '%lol%'
```

Если слов больше одного, и без OR, если просто одно слово

```
`word` LIKE '%Lala%'
```

Comment: делайте join вместо foreach :)

Comment: Я вам писал пример с `implode()`, проскочило мимо сознания?

Comment: Мне так привычнее просто ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN не совсем подходит,т.к. лишняя нагрузка - если 10 условий, то делать 10 join ?

По поводу вопроса:
Ты все правильно делаешь - только после цикла напиши **rtrim($where,'OR')**.

**rtrim** при любом раскладе отрежет последний *OR*.

```
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $msg);
foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
  $where .= "`word` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR"; 
}
$where = rtrim($where,'OR');
```

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, это с какого бока `join()` - лишняя нагрузка? И откуда там больше одного join возьмётся?

Comment: господа, вы перепутали джойны. @eicto дал ссылку на функцию в PHP, синоним implode. @Автостопом_до_Рая имеет в виду JOIN в базе данных - в данном вопросе он не упоминался :)

Comment: Ну что за ответ, в самом деле?? SQL Injection жe ж. Попробуйте задать вот такую строку 

    $msg = "one,two,' or '%' = ',four";

Comment: Простой вопрос - простой ответ. Я сомневаюсь, что автора волнует возможность sql-инъекции

Comment: То есть цикл и лишний `trim()` вместо однострочного `join/implode` - это проще?

Comment: Sql не будет работать использую 1 бд class в котором есть функция filter(), но даже если забуду про фильтр бд класс sql не пустит
An error has occurred:

Error at 2014-06-20 11:38:16: Query:

Severity: Fatal

Comment: @klopp, т.е. предлагаешь  $where = "`word` LIKE';$where.=implode('OR `word LIKE `',$keywords); ? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну да, зачем лишний геморрой?

`$where = 'WHERE wrd LIKE  "%'.join('%" OR wrd LIKE "%', $words).'%"'`

Собственно, этот вариант был предложен автору ещё вчера, но не понравился: "непривычно" ему :-)

Comment: Ну так гораздо компактнее, но теряется читаемость кода.
Спасибо за идею, сам юзал только цикл, сейчас вот думаю можно будет использовать join, когда не надо будет как-либо обрабатывать значения (trim-ить или iconv) =) 
Up твой!

Answer (score 3):

Пишите OR в начале, т.е. начните с заведомо ложного условия, а потом "орьте" все остальные, т.е.

```
WHERE 1=0 OR `word` LIKE '%Lala%' [и т.д.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Пукну таким кодом

```
$msg = ' lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ';
//$msg = 'lorem';

if(preg_match('/\s/', trim($msg)))
{
    $key = preg_split('/[\s]+/', trim($msg));

    $where = '`word` LIKE %' . join('% OR LIKE %', $key) . '%';
}
else
{
    $where = '`word` LIKE %' . trim($msg) . '%';
}

echo $where;
```